# React / Redux / Data loading at router level or at the component level?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using react-redux with es6. I'm coming from angular and learning about data loading and doing http requests.

As for angular, it was usually best to create your own services and inject them into your components. AFAIK.

Is there any differences between loading data at the router level then at the component level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean with "at router level" and the concept of Services does not exist in React/Redux. For one project I have created Middelware to do the remote stuff, what is working very nice. So would recommend to use middleware for that

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html